# How to change default javadoc stylesheet?

Tags: stylesheet, javadoc

Is there a command line option to change the stylesheet file created by javadoc?
I would like to use my own css file.
The default blue one is boring. I tried a -stylesheet option, but it's not supported.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's possible and actually quite straightforward. If you look for example at Mockito's javadoc:

- http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html (you can see that they have changed the default appereance just using [this stylesheet](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/stylesheet.css))

If you are using Maven, you can do that by adding some config in the maven-javadoc-plugin:

- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/stylesheet-configuration.html.

In case you are using ant, there is a way to inject the parameter to the javadoc tool:

- http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html

For more information, there are some discussion topics about that in stackoverflow: [JavaDoc Style Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499967/javadoc-style-sheets)

Comment: Both links are dead!

Answer (score 0):

For the maven-javadoc-plugin, you can also use:

```
<configuration>
  <addStylesheets>our-stylesheet.css</addStylesheets>
</configuration>
```

which keeps the primary stylesheet, but then also adds the custom one, so that all you need to do is override the rules you want.

Put `our-stylesheet.css` in the `src/main/javadoc` directory.